# Deserialize JSON string with Date Headings - C# - No JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, csv, serialization

I need to deserialize and/or export to csv a JSON string being sent back to me. The problem is that the JSON string is formatted in a way that results dates being used as the headers.

See example below:

```
{"2017-01-09":{"chats":129,"missed_chats":0},
"2017-01-10":{"chats":347,"missed_chats":0},
"2017-01-11":{"chats":194,"missed_chats":0},
"2017-01-12":{"chats":229,"missed_chats":0}}
```

Because of this, I do not believe I can make a class to hold them as each date would need its own class to match the heading of "2017-01-09", and so on. I need to keep the dates as data, so setting my own headers for the csv file programmatically is perfectly fine.

I am not able to use any add ins for visual studio such as JSON.Net, so the built in tool only or some other work around.

Thank you

Comment: JSON.NET is not an "addin".  Its a library and the first words on MSDN for [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) are to use JSON.NET for non web/ajax uses.  Doing so, you could write a converter very easily

Comment: All right, I have installed the JSON.Net library. Do you have a recommendation on how to create this converter? Or a link to something similar that I could use as a reference? I have having trouble finding similar JSON string formats.

Comment: The answer provided below is what you need as a reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialise to a `Dictionary`, something like this:

```
public class InnerThing
{
    public int Chats { get; set; }
    public int Missed_Chats { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, InnerThing>>(json);
```

Comment: Yes this did help. I was confused on how it was storing the dates and how to retrieve them. After looking at other examples I was able to pull the data back out of these. Thank you.